# How to set limited width of text in uitextfield

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, width, limit

I need to set limited width of text in my `UITextField`, because I put button on top of that `UITextField`

look at image:

[image]

how that can be done?

Comment: Is this a UITableViewCell? If so it has a easy way to do this with accessoryView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to subclass the UITextField and override editingRectForBounds: method. Try something like this..Of course adjust values accordingly.

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
      return CGRectInset( bounds , 10 , 10 );
}
```

Accept this answer if it's the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can link the event `editingChanged` of the UITextView to the following method:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldChanged:(id)sender{
    if([sender.text length]>6){ 
        sender.text = [sender.text substringToIndex: 6];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1--I've done something similar before. You have to be careful if you're not using a monospace font, though, because then this won't always work.

Comment: With this solution, you're limiting the text to 6 characters, I don't think this is desired. He only wants to change the inset so the characters aren't covered by the button. See my solution..

Comment: I understood that he just wanted to limit the size of the text, like you can enter up to 10 characters.

Comment: Another option is to put the real uitextview with the desired width and no borders in front of a disabled uitextview on the backgrownd. This way it would obtain the desired effect while looking like it is a UITextView witha button.

Comment: Thanks to all.. I will remember your methods

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, you'll probably want to override both `editingRectForBounds` and `textRectForBounds` so that the text is correctly displayed when editing and not editing (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535760/uitextfield-textrectforbounds-vs-editingrectforbounds)).  In Swift, this might be:

```
class MyUITextField: UITextField {

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, 18, 0)
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, 18, 0)
    }
}
```