# What are borderRect, editingRect, placeholderRect, textRect in UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535760/uitextfield-textrectforbounds-vs-editingrectforbounds) previously posted, I understand that `editingRect` is the rectangle shown when the text is being edited, and `textRect` is the one shown when the text is not being edited. But I don't know where exactly `placeholderRect` and `borderRect` are displayed in a UITextField control. I assumed the `borderRect` would be the same as the frame rect of UITextField because of the word 'border' in it, but after doing this:

```
override func borderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let rect = bounds
    rect.size.height = 150 //the height of my UITextField currently is 100
    return rect
}
```

I realized it was not. So what are `placeholderRect` and `borderRect`, and where are they located in UITextField?

Comment: Judging from their names, `placeholderRect` is the frame of the placeholder text, and `borderRect` is the frame of the text field's border. FYI, if you set `borderStyle` to something other than `none`, the text field would have a border.

Comment: That's what I thought so if you read the question I did change the height in `borderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {...}` hoping to see the text field's frame updated, but no effect! ='(

Comment: That could be because the rect you returned exceeds the bounds that you are given. I just tried it with a smaller rect than the `bounds` parameter, and it works as expected.

Comment: Can you please share your answer in the Answer section? Because when I reduce the height I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`borderRect` refers to the frame of the border (which will exist for a text field if `borderStyle != .none`), and `placeholderRect` refers to the frame of the placeholder text - the text that appears when `text` is empty.

Here is a little sample that you can paste into a playground, that shows where all the rects are. I returned different quarters the `bounds` rect for each of the text field rects.

```
class TextFieldWithDifferentRects: UITextField {
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // top left
        CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width / 2, height: bounds.height / 2)
    }
    
    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // top right
        CGRect(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width / 2, height: bounds.height / 2)
    }
    
    override func borderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // bottom left
        CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY, width: bounds.width / 2, height: bounds.height / 2)
    }
    
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // bottom right
        CGRect(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY, width: bounds.width / 2, height: bounds.height / 2)
    }
}

let view = TextFieldWithDifferentRects(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = .white // make the placeholder text more visible
view.borderStyle = .line
view.placeholder = "a" // use the playground quick view button here
view.text = "b" // and here

// by selecting everything, we kick the text field into edit mode, to show the editingRect
view.selectAll(nil) // and lastly here
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is an unbelievable answer.. Now I see where each rect are in UITextField. So amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

From Apple Docs:

**placeholderRect(forBounds:)** [(Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619615-placeholderrect)

> Returns the drawing rectangle for the text field’s placeholder text

**borderRect(forBounds:)** [(Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619642-borderrect)

> Returns the text field’s border rectangle.

Comment: I read that part too. What I want to know is where they are actually located in a UITextField control.